# Convert Curl into R using RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl

I need to query this curl code in R:

```
curl -u user:pwd \
     -k https://localhost/adapars/apply/Iris_NN?maxThreads=8 \
     -X POST -F \
     file=@Iris_NN.csv
```

I am using `RCurl` but I don't really see how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `httr`

not tested, but:

```
library("httr")
url = "https://localhost/adapars/apply/Iris_NN?maxThreads=8"
POST(url, authenticate("user", "pwd"), body=list(file = upload_file("Iris_NN.csv")))
```

Comment: it actually worked with a small modification:

library("httr")
url = "https://localhost/adapars/apply/IrisMLRModel"
data<-POST(url, authenticate("user", "pwd"), body=list(file=upload_file("iris1.csv")))

Comment: okay, thanks, i'll update the code block above